# Concatinated date not coming in Excel filename

Tags: apache-poi

I am concatenating date in the Excel file name (Created by Java using Apache POI).when I print the filname with sysout in the console I can see full name but when I download that file, in the file name concatenated date is not coming.

And surprise thing is -- just I hard coded date as String with =1234568 its showing in the file name but when I hard coded with date format like 20170323 its not showing in the file after download.

Comment: Hi Axel thanks alot for your response..here is my file format........... 
   String date="12345678" 
final String filename =date + "_" + table.getTableName() + fileFormat.getExtensionWithDot();                                                                                              like this i have my file format when i give string like that its coming the filename..but when i give string like required date format- 20170223 this is not coming in the file name..but when i give format like 23-02-2017 its coming in the file name.it looks like that format is not allowing in the file name.

Comment: what "is not coming in the filename"--the concatenated String = "20170223" is not concatenating in the  file name.                                        "it is coming in the filename"   ---if i conctenate String ="12345678" its coming in the filename.                                                                               are you using the concatenated string to be the file name--yes ..concatenated string is the first prefix of the filename and this is appending with some other values.

Comment: Actually the problem is i am creating excel sheet by using apache POI.And i am trying to concatenate business as a prefix for the  file name.when i am printing the file name with sysout i can see the file name with my concatenated business date.but when i download that file from UI in the file name i can't see the conatinated business date this is the issue please let me know if you need any further input from me.

Comment: for downloading i have used wicket with Ajax

Comment: this is i have used.                                                                                                      <input type="submit" wicket:id="datadictionary" value="[DOWNLOAD EXCEL]"/>